# Editing some properties of View Model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using *Entity Framework Database First* approach. Let's say I have a model class called `Product` and that class has a `NumberOfViews` property. In the *Edit* page I pass an instance of the `product` *class* to the *controller*.

The problem is I can't add `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfViews)` in the *Edit* page, because it's supposed that `NumberOfViews` is updated with every visit to the product page, and **NOT** by the website Admin.

And I can't add it as `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NumberOfViews)`, because if the Admin *Inspected the element*, he can edit it manually.

Also If I try to programmatically set the value on the server-side (e.g., `Product.NumberOfViews = db.Products.Find(Product.Id).NumberOfViews;`), I get the following error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

And if I don't add it to either the view or the controller, the value will be `null`, thus overriding any previous value.

So what should I do?

Comment: If your really concerned that a malicious user may change the hidden input you can add a second hidden input with a hashed value of it as described in [this article](http://blog.slatner.com/2010/01/20/SecuringFormValuesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

Comment: Total aside, but: in .NET, public members (e.g., properties and methods) are usually PascalCase not camelCase, as per [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you, and specially @JeremyCaney :)

Comment: I don't think the view should do this in the first place. It should be done server-side in the action method that shows the product, dependent of the role of the user. How else would you handle concurrent views for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed a lot of people use the same model for their Entity Framework as they do for their MVC Controller. I generally discourage this practice. In my opinion, a database model is not the same as a view model.

Sometimes a view needs less information than what the database model is supplying. For example while modifying account password, view does not need first name, last name, or email address even though they may all reside in the same table.

Sometimes it needs information from more than one database table. For example if a user can store unlimited number of telephone numbers for their profile, then user information will be in user table and then contact information with be in contact table. However when modifying user profile, they may want to add/edit/delete one or more of their numbers, so the view needs all of the numbers along with first name, last name and email address.

This is what I would do in your case:

```
// This is your Entity Framework Model class
[Table("Product")]
public class Product 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfPageViews { get; set; }
}

// This is the model you will use in your Edit action.
public class EditProductViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductController : Controller
{
    IProductService service;

    //...

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int productId)
    {
        var product = service.GetProduct(productId);
        var model = new EditProductViewModel() 
        {
            ProductId = product.ProductId,
            Name = product.Name
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditProductViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var product = service.GetProduct(model.ProductId);
            product.Name = model.Name;
            service.Update(product);
        }

        // ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and solution, but I think that would force me to switch to _code first_ approach, because as far as I know edits to model class in _database first_ approach will be overridden if I made changes to the database -which may happen-. So, I can make that switch in future projects, but it would be very costing to make to the current one.

Comment: Oh my bad. I misread database first to code first. Ignore the Product class.